# Display the desired field in Gridview

Tags: c#, devexpress

Hello There is a table in Gridview2 on my form which is named List. When I run the project that I want to do, I click on any of the listed names in the Gridview2 and I want the Gridview1 to come to that area. By the way Surname is the common area on both grids. How can you help me to be delighted!

```
string Surname = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "SURNAME"));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpIV3.png)

Comment: I don't see any SQL. Please consider removing the SQL tag or elaborate your question to include any SQL that plays a role in this.

Comment: Dear sticky..I am extracting the table data from the sql database.

Comment: Yes. But... you probably run that program on a computer running Windows <version> using an Intel <model number> CPU with a <brand> monitor and <brand> keyboard in your house in <city> in <country>. But you didn't tag these, because they are not relevant for the question. I think you get my point. ;)

Comment: I've added an image, maybe give some idea! :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a system wherein you can click/double-click on a name in grid 1 and then display all the data filtered by that name in grid #2? BTW, using surname to perform this operation is probably a bad choice, as many different people can have the same surname. It would be a better choice to use a unique identifier for each pilot and then a foreign key relationship to their flights.

Comment: You are understand absolutely right Brendon...Right Now I just have to use the last name, then I can develop and change. If you can help with the encoding part,I will be so happy. Thnx

Comment: Is the data already loaded in Grid #2, or are you just going to be performing a database query based on the value from Grid #1?

Comment: already loaded on all tables, What is the only code I need right now? I need to write Csharp to the code field. Whan I click in the Gridview2 to any person display of the field belonging to that person in Gridview1.

Answer (score 0):

```
string Surname = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView2.FocusedRowHandle, "SURNAME").ToString();
```